# How to disable automatic updates on Fedora 25?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, automatic-update, dnf

The title is sufficient I think. How can I stop Fedora to automatically download and install system and software updates on restart?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

dnf is a background service that updates the repository metadata automatically.
dnf makecache is scheduled to run after every reboot

To disable dnf-makecache.service:

```
systemctl disable dnf-makecache.service
```

Also disable the dnf-makecache.timer or the service will be restarted:

```
systemctl disable dnf-makecache.timer
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted the answer. I just wonder if commands are the only option to disable updates on Fedora 25, is it possible through editing configuration files as well?

Comment: Note that you _also_ will need to separately disable packagekit refreshes. This is a known problem and I'm optimistic that we'll get this solved in the next release (but not F25). `gsettings set org.gnome.software download-updates false`

Comment: the mattdm comment has to be in the answer, seems to be the obligatory piece of the puzzle as everything else was kinda disabled

Comment: Even after setting download-updates=false in gsettings, it's downloading huge metadata files which is very very annoying. I'm trying to use fedora after long time Ubuntu and this reminded me why I chose ubuntu first.